# Alternating cApS using Unix commands

Tags: regex, unix, sed, awk, tr

Purely just for fun, I was wondering how to transform all lower case text into upper case for every other letter, using either `awk`, `sed`, `tr`, regex or any other Unix tool except for Python or Perl.

So far I've tried

```
echo "hello" | sed s/\([a-z]\)/\U\1/g
```

the desired output should be `HeLlO`. I would appreciate if anyone can improve this or offer an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `awk` method for you:

```
echo "hello" | awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2)$i=toupper($i)}1' FS= OFS=
HeLlO
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's/[a-z].\?/\u\0/g' <<< hello
HeLlO
```

(Disclaimer: this may depend on non-standard features. I ran it on GNU sed version 4.2.1.)

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/[[:lower:]][^[:alpha:]]*\([[:alpha:]]\|$\)/\u&/g' file
```